# Formatting XML with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to create an XML file using XmlDocument that will then be passed to an API. Most of the data outputs correctly however there is one element that does not, no matter what I try.

Here is my current output

```
<agentInventoryReference xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryReference"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<agentInventoryIdentity xmlns="">
<shed xmlns="demo.org.uk/demom/AgentInventoryIdentifier">TAX</shed> 
<arrivalPort xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier">LHR</arrivalPort> 
<masterAirwayBillPrefix xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier">125</masterAirwayBillPrefix> 
<masterAirwayBillNumber xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier">12345678</masterAirwayBillNumber> 
<nominatedAgent xmlns="demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier">DRB</nominatedAgent> 
</agentInventoryIdentity>
```

I need to drop the xmlns="" at the end of the opening agentInventoryIdentity element.

My code looks like this:

```
 XmlDocument generateInventoryXml = new XmlDocument();
 XmlElement root = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement  ("agentInventoryReference", "demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryReference");
        root.SetAttribute("xmlns", "demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryReference");
        root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
        generateInventoryXml.AppendChild(root);

        XmlElement agentInventoryIdentity = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("agentInventoryIdentity");

        XmlElement shed = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("shed", "demo.org.uk/Sequoia/AgentInventoryIdentifier");
        XmlElement arrivalport = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("arrivalPort", "demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier");
        XmlElement masterAirwayBillPrefix = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("masterAirwayBillPrefix","demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier");
        XmlElement masterAirwayBillNumber = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("masterAirwayBillNumber", "demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier");
        XmlElement nominatedAgent = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("nominatedAgent", "demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryIdentifier");

        shed.InnerText = shedCode;
        arrivalport.InnerText = arrivalPort;
        masterAirwayBillPrefix.InnerText = awbPrefix;
        masterAirwayBillNumber.InnerText = awbNumber;
        nominatedAgent.InnerText = agent;

        agentInventoryIdentity.AppendChild(shed);
        agentInventoryIdentity.AppendChild(arrivalport);
        agentInventoryIdentity.AppendChild(masterAirwayBillPrefix);
        agentInventoryIdentity.AppendChild(masterAirwayBillNumber);
        agentInventoryIdentity.AppendChild(nominatedAgent);

        generateInventoryXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(agentInventoryIdentity);

        GenerateInventoryXml = generateInventoryXml.InnerXml;
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the `xmlns` from XDocument ?

Comment: Just from the <agentInventoryIdentity xmlns=""> element

Comment: Your title says `XDocument`, but your code is using `XmlDocument` - changing your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlElement agentInventoryIdentity = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("agentInventoryIdentity",generateInventoryXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);`
```

Or

```
XmlElement agentInventoryIdentity = generateInventoryXml.CreateElement("agentInventoryIdentity","demo.org.uk/demo/AgentInventoryReference");
```